# can't extract value from parsed data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am a beginner and trying hands on Json parsing. I am successfully parsing the data I need. But the problem is I don't know how to save and use that value in another function.

For now, I am doing everything in view controller.m for the sake of simplicity. Meaning all my code is in viewcontroller.m
Will later use a separate class.

I have a button and a label on my storyboard. So I am trying to fetch a value from Json .api and want to show that value in label. When user presses button, the parsing is triggered. As u can c below.

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:........myweb"];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connection)
    {
        webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        self.outputLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", goldRate];
    }
```

but the value printed in the label is null. when we fetch info and display in tableviews, we set delegates. but for a label we don't set delegate. So I am confused what the problem is? have i forgot to set a delegate or am i passing data incorrectly. pls the function below.

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *myDataArray=[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *myGoldArray=[myDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    goldRate=[[myGoldArray objectAtIndex:1] stringValue];

}
```

I have made this goldRate a global variable. But when I debug my program. In the connectionDidFinishLoading, the goldRate value is absolutely what I want. But when I try to use this goldRate in btnPressed function, in that function the value is null.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the button is pressed, you initiate a load. When the load completes (some time later) the connectionDidFinishLoading: method is called. But until that happens, "goldRate" will be nil (because it is not yet initialized).

Set the label in the connectionDidFinishLoading: instead of where you have it, and the value will show up.

Comment: Thanks that does work. but is there a way I can pass this value from connectionDidFinishLoading to another method/function in my code? Cos if I try to pass value to another function by giving a call from connectionDidFinishLoading it doesn't save the value.

Comment: You could make it a member variable